# Liferay Portlet Response: how to set status code?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have a simple method accepting PortletResponse and PortletRequest in my liferay portlet

```
public void remove(PortletResponse response, PortletRequest request) {

}
```

I want to set response status to 404, like I can do with HttpServletResponse by `httpResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)`

Can you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: Perhaps try asking on Liferay's support forums? https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/category/243728

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What does [Portlet Specification 2.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr286/index.html) have to say - you can set the response status only when handling resource request:

> If the portlet want to set a response status code it should do this
>   via `setProperty` with the key `ResourceResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE`.

That means, you can set the response status code this way when serving resources:

```
resourceResponse.setProperty(ResourceResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, 
                             Integer.toString(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST));
```

With Liferay, you can get instance of the underlying `HttpServletResponse` and set status code there. The portal will return it to the client. This way, you can set the response status for any portal request, not only resource request.

```
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
```

However, such practice is *strongly discouraged* as well explained in Olaf Kock's answer. See it to get the bigger picture.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tomas Pinos' answer (please accept his answer): Note that a portlet is never delivered directly by an HttpServletRequest - it's embedded in a page which is generated by the portal. Thus the HTTP response codes don't have any meaning (for portlets) in the portal world: The page might still be there, just contain or not contain the portlet in question - it's the business of the portal to show whatever it likes then.

The only exception to this rule is what Tomas describes correctly: When handling a resource request, you're serving exclusive content - thus you have the option to do more to the request than just piping HTML that would otherwise be embedded in a page generated by someone else (the portal, together with other unknown portlets)